# jquery click() loads blank page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use a button to toggle visibility of two divs.

See "Shop by Occasion" and "Shop by Recipient" [here](http://198.57.247.171/~bigmouthinc/products/)

Site is Wordpress with _strap (underscores + bootstrap)

Buttons:

```
<div><button data-toggle="#form_occ">Shop by Occasion</button> or <button data-toggle="#form_per">Shop by Recipient</button></div>
```

jQuery (WP)

```
 jQuery("button[data-toggle]").click(function() {
  var selector = jQuery(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
  jQuery("div").hide();
  jQuery(selector).show();
});
```

I thought maybe the  element in bootstrap was an issue, but the same blank page happens using  or  as the click() element.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Ymj/) is the fiddle I'm emulating

THE FIX:

I used the same markup and code, but instead of hiding ALL div's (duh!), I added a class to isolate only the two div's I want to show/hide.

```
<div id="form_occ" class="form"><!--occasion form-->
<div id="form_occ" class="form"><!--occasion form-->

jQuery("button[data-toggle]").click(function() {
  var selector = jQuery(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
  jQuery("div.form").hide();
  jQuery(selector).show();
});
```

If anyone finds value in this answer, how about voting up my question!

Comment: `jQuery("div").hide();` hides every div on the page.

Comment: does the click function run ?

Comment: As usual, I missed something obvious! Thanks to all who pointed out my mistake. BTW, I'm really trying to write good questions. Would love to know why my questions was down voted? Is there something wrong with the question or the way I asked it? Or was it down voted b/c the issue I was having was so obvious to more experienced viewers?

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted. It's a bit basic, but we should be open to helping beginners as well as experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery("div").hide();` hides every div on the page, essentially making the whole page "blank". `jQuery(selector).show();` would show the part you want to show, except you've just made its parents invisible. `jQuery(selector).parents().show();` shows more of the page, but I doubt that's what you really want. You really want to only hide the bits that should be hidden, not the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding all `div` elements and some of them are parents of the selected div you want to show. Consider this approach: hide only the opposite `div` element:

`<div><button data-toggle="#form_per">Shop by Occasion</button> or <button data-toggle="#form_occ">Shop by Recipient</button></div>`

```
jQuery("button[data-toggle]").click(function() {
   var selector = jQuery(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
   jQuery(selector).hide();
});
```

**EDIT**
To show the other `div` element just change the `data-toggle` attribute of the two `button` elements to `data-hide-element` and add another `data-show-element` attribute like this:

`<div><button data-hide-element="#form_per" data-show-element="#form_occ">Shop by Occasion</button> or <button data-hide-element="#form_occ" data-show-element="#form_per">Shop by Recipient</button></div>`

Then change your JS code to:

```
jQuery("button[data-show-element]").click(function() {
   var button = jQuery(this);
   var showElementSelector = button.data("showElement");
   var hideElementSelector = button.data("hideElement");
   jQuery(showElementSelector).show();
   jQuery(hideElementSelector).hide();
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it just hides the corresponding div without showing the other one. What solved my problem was adding a class to both div's so the hide/show toggle only targeted those particular div's.

Comment: I edited my answer to follow your requirements. :) PS Sorry for the late answer - I had to drive and wasn't able to write...

Answer (score 1):

what jQuery('div').hide(); does is it hides everything on the page. What you need to do is to only hide the other div. I made a small addition that should make that happen. However, keep in mind that this is not as clean as it should be because it counts on there only being two buttons.

```
jQuery("button[data-toggle]").click(function() {
  var selector = jQuery(this).data('toggle');  // get corresponding element
  var other = jQuery(this).siblings('button').data('toggle');
  jQuery(other).hide();
  jQuery(selector).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you were hiding the overall container. Here is a working model.

```js
$("button[data-toggle]").click(function() {
  $(".shopBy").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <button data-toggle="#form_occ">Shop by Occasion</button> 
  or 
  <button data-toggle="#form_per">Shop by Recipient</button>
</div>
<div class="shopBy"><h2>Shopping by Occassion</h2></div><div class="shopBy ui-helper-hidden"><h2>Shopping by Recipient</h2></div>
```